# How to remove the first & last slash from a url if it's exists?

Tags: php, regex

I use parse_url() to get the path of a url but i want to remove the first slash & the last if it's exists.

Example:

```
"/posts/funny-dog/" -> "posts/funny-dog"
"/" -> "" // Because http://www.google.com/ path is a slash
"/categories/politic" -> "categories/politics"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`trim( $str, "/" );` is probably your best/fastest bet.

Comment: How could I remove only the last slash if it exists?

Comment: @BenjaminGoodacre the `rtrim` method, basically does the same but only on the right side (end).

Comment: @CharlesLeaf Great. Now the code is working even if user places a trailing slash. Thanks.